# Lat-Lon Point is in rectangle defined by two other Lat-Lon points

Tags: java, geometry, latitude-longitude

I would like to determine if a certain point is contained within a 'rectangle'. The 'rectangle' will be made up of latitude/longitude coordinates (given northWest and southEast coordinate points)... so basically here are the parameters:

```
public boolean hasPoint(LatLon northWest, LatLon southEast, LatLon point) {}
```

The LatLon class just has:
double latitude;
double longitude;

I have no idea how to start this... any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is not a coding question, it's simple logic. Work it out on paper, then convert it to code.

Comment: Work out what is needed for the point to be in the rectangle, and go on from there.

Comment: start with writing a test. call hasPoint with different numbers you worked on the paper and verify what the return value should be. then you can start actually writing hasPoint code.

Comment: Are you familiar with Java's relational operators?  And does your `LatLon` class have getter methods for the latitude and the longitude?

Comment: Will the northern and southern boundaries of your "rectangle" be lines of latitude, or great circles?  If it's the latter, this is a very difficult problem; if it's the former, it's very easy.

Comment: I can see a tricky bit being round the other side of the globe, if the rectangle sits over the 180th meridian.

Comment: @weston Great circles are the "spherical geometry" equivalent of straight lines.  A "rectangle" on the surface of the sphere would have great circles for its sides.  But like I said, that makes this a very difficult problem.  It's far easier to pretend that lines of latitude are straight.

Comment: @DavidWallace Why does it matter though if the lines are bent? The point being tested is in the same coordinate system.

Comment: @weston It matters because the point could be inside the great-circle-rectangle but outside the almost-rectangle made of lines of latitude and longitude; or vice versa.

Comment: No, @weston, lines of latitude are NOT (generally) great circles.

Comment: @DavidWallace Ah! With you now. Thanks for explaining. I guess just the equator is?

Comment: That is correct.  The equator is a great circle.  So are lines of longitude.  But most lines of latitude aren't.

Comment: @DavidWallace Shame they only want the simple solution, the other is a far more interesting problem.

Comment: OP hasn't actually said which they want.  I suspect they haven't thought about it. In any case, if you want to provide an answer to the more difficult problem, go right ahead.  If you get the mathematics right, I promise you an upvote.

Comment: It's not about wanting a 'simple solution'. I wanted the solution that was applicable for the task I wished to carry out -- simplicity is irrelevant to discuss here , @weston. Thanks for the comment. 

Nonetheless, I was able to figure out the solution. Thank you all for your responses & a very intriguing discussion!

Comment: No offence intended by "simple". Well done on doing it, post your solution for future visitors plus critique.

Comment: @DavidWallace I might take you up on that. OP did say they wanted "the former" of your two solutions, but then deleted that comment later.

Comment: @user7696456 Are you going to post your solution?

Comment: @user7696456 Future visitors finding this question would like an answer. Why don't you post your solution?

Comment: My solution was quite simple, I just checked whether the point is within the boundaries of the given Latitude and Longitude points using simple mathematical operations.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming this LatLon class just has an x and y value.
How about just checking if your point x/y lies between the x/y from your other 2 positions ?

Comment: x and y? They said it had `double latitude; double longitude;`